# keeping a drawing canvas visible behind an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

I wonder if anyone could assist me with this?

I am writing a webpage with a drawing area ("GraphicsArea", below) that loads a map as a SVG image into the innerHTML of the "DiagramArea" div contained in it.  The SVG has defined areas which have events attached to them and css styling that allows me to highlight areas as I mouseover them, and fill them with a highlight colour when I click on them.  This all works fine.

I have, superimposed over the "DiagramArea", a HTML5 canvas element ("CanvasArea").  I have some javascript that allows me to draw inside this freehand with the mouse.  The canvas is transparent, and I can see the map underneath it when I draw.

I can toggle between the drawing canvas layer and the "DiagramArea" with the SVG which I am using as an imagemap, by setting zIndex.  I have a button that does this, allowing me to swap between functionality to highlight areas of the map, and the freehand drawing functionality.

My problem is that if I toggle away from the canvas, its drawing is hidden while I use the image map functionality.  I can toggle it back again to display the drawing overlay after I have highlighted the areas I want to highlight, but it's a bit clumsy

Is there a way to keep the canvas contents visible while I'm using the rollover and click events attached to the SVG?  I'm not particularly fussy as to whether it's a style or code solution.  I'd prefer to avoid having to use an external library, if possible.

```
<div id="GraphicsArea">
    <canvas id='CanvasArea'></canvas>
    <div id="DiagramArea"></div>
</div>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: sounds like you want to manipulate pointer-events rather than z-index.

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly the answer I was looking for.  I was barking up completely the wrong tree by trying to work out whether there was some version of z-index and transparency that would allow me to do this.

So, as per Robert's suggestion, if I set [pointer-events:none;] on my canvas element, it cancels all user events on current (canvas) layer and passes them to the elements below (i.e.: the svg with all its rollovers and events listeners).  Consequently, I can keep the canvas layer visible while still being able to click on the image below.

Thank you.